# How to split an specified number of elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array below:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
```

and the length of the array is 20 and i am spliting it with 5

When i specify 1, it should return [1,2,3,4,5] and if i specify 2, it should return [6,7,8,9,10]

How can i get it through scripting?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.slice()` method to return a segment from an array.

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

For your case, you'd do something like this.

```
arr.slice(5 * n, 5 * n + 5)
```

Comment: It should be `n-1` for OP's case.

Comment: I think you meant to link Array.slice and not Array.splice :)

Comment: Nice and simple, I like it (I completely forgot about the .slice() function too!)